# Node is gone with facet pivot query SolrCloud (solr 5)

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, sharding, solrcloud, solr5

We have a **shard-3 SolrCloud** with **Zookeeper**. Sometimes after we do a `pivot query` the node that we are accessing for the query is gone and soon all the system collapse.

**Solr** logs do not show anything but **Zookeerper** shows the following warning, just before the node is gone. Any help?

---

Zookeper Logs:

> 2015-06-01 12:25:12,633 [myid:] - WARN 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught
>   end of stream exception EndOfStreamException: Unable to read
>   additional data from client sessionid 0x14d473d19d20003, likely client
>   has closed socket
>
> at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:12,634 [myid:] - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] -
>   Closed socket connection for client /172.31.10.187:46214 which had
>   sessionid 0x14d473d19d20003
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,000 [myid:] - INFO 
>   [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@347] - Expiring session
>   0x14d473d19d20003, timeout of 15000ms exceeded
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,000 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@494] - Processed session termination
>   for sessionid: 0x14d473d19d20003
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,004 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d2001a type:delete cxid:0xd9
>   zxid:0xc96 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error
>   Path:/collections/netOpinionVolumen/leaders/shard3
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for
>   /collections/netOpinionVolumen/leaders/shard3
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,004 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:delete cxid:0x11f5
>   zxid:0xc97 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer_elect/leader
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /overseer_elect/leader
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,007 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d2001a type:create cxid:0xda
>   zxid:0xc98 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,012 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x11fa
>   zxid:0xc9b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,015 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x11fb
>   zxid:0xc9c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,017 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x11fd
>   zxid:0xc9d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,019 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x11ff
>   zxid:0xc9e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,021 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x1201
>   zxid:0xc9f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,022 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x1203
>   zxid:0xca0 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,031 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x1206
>   zxid:0xca1 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,033 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x1208
>   zxid:0xca2 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,035 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x120a
>   zxid:0xca3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:26,036 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d20014 type:create cxid:0x120c
>   zxid:0xca4 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer
>
> 2015-06-01 12:25:28,519 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0
>   cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException
>   when processing sessionid:0x14d473d19d2001a type:create cxid:0xe5
>   zxid:0xcaa txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/overseer
>   Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /overseer